# Importing phone/fax/mobile phone numbers from CSV.....best practices?

Tags: contacts, import, database, phone

I'm about to do my first import of contacts into a pre-existing CiviCRM database on WordPress. Client sent over the CSV but there are columns like this:

Home Phone
Home Fax
Mobile Phone
Work Phone
Work Fax

That's fine, but in the DB, the Contact Details set has a Phone field and two dropdowns, one for Phone Location and one for Phone Type. And the ability to add more numbers. So what's the best way to take this CSV and properly do an import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that home and work are location types in your Civi?  If that is in fact the case, the one question I would ask from what you included is what location type to assign to the mobile phone.  Home and work would be location types, and phone type would be phone, mobile, or fax.  You would then set up your mapping in the contact import to assign the correct location and phone types to each column. Here is a sample of what I mean:

[image]

(I chose home as the location type for the mobile but that might not be correct in your situation.)

Hope this helps,
Lesley

Comment: Yes, I figured this out when testing out my first import. Pretty cool system. Thanks for confirming that for me.